# Emacs macro: check if it is function name

Tags: emacs, macros

I want to write macro like this.

```
A_ret A_function_name (A_param ap)
{
 A_sentence;
}
```

after do macro in emacs, change A to B if it is on function name.

```
A_ret B_function_name (A_param ap)
{
 A_sentence;
}
```

how can I check 'A' is on function name in macro definition?

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking. Firstly, what are you using to implement your "macro" ? (n.b. that's not good terminology for emacs, which provides both lisp macros and keyboard macros, neither of which are what you are alluding to as far as I can tell). Secondly what do you mean by "after do macro in emacs, change A to B if it is on function name"? I don't understand the sentence. What does "do macro" actually mean in this context? What specifically is "it"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to write a keyboard macro that is conditional on the current symbol.  You can type `C-x q` to pause a keyboard macro and have Emacs ask you whether to proceed or not (`Y` or `N`).

If you're trying to replace a lot of function names, I'd use `C-M-%` (`M-x query-replace-regexp`) to do a search and replace with regular expressions or if that is too complicated, then use `M-s o` (`M-x occur`) with keyboard macros to find all the matches for `A_\(\s_\|\sw\)+ (` (`\sw` are word characters and `\s_` are symbol characters including the underscore `_`).

To use `occur` with a keyboard macro, I would

```
M-s o A_\(\s_\|\sw\)+ RET [occur]
RET [exit-minibuffer]
C-x ( [kmacro-start-macro]
C-x ` [next-error]
C-x [kbd-macro-query]
M-d  [kill-word]
B_ [self-insert-command]
C-x ) [kmacro-end-query]
C-x e [kmacro-call-query]
C-x e [kmacro-call-query]
C-x e [kmacro-call-query]
...
```

To be honest, I don't use `C-x q`.  Instead, I'll use `C-x e` to execute, and ``C-x ``` if I want to skip to the next match without executing.

```
M-s o A_\(\s_\|\sw\)+ RET [occur]
C-x ` [next-error]
C-x ( [kmacro-start-macro]
M-d  [kill-word]
B_ [self-insert-command]
C-x e [kmacro-call-query]
C-x e [kmacro-call-query]
...
C-x ` [next-error]
```

But that's me.